# Coin in circle probability.

Tags: probability

> In a common carnival game a player tosses a penny from a distance of about
>   5 feet onto the surface of a table ruled in I-inch squares. If the penny (i inch
>   in diameter) falls entirely inside a square, the player receives 5 cents but does
>   not get his penny back; otherwise he loses his penny. If the penny lands on the
>   table, what is his chance to win?

Now, here's the solution provided.

> When we toss the coin onto the
>   table, some positions for the center of
>   the coin are more likely than others,
>   but over a very small square we can
>   regard the probability distribution as
>   uniform. This means that the proba-
>   bility that the center falls into any
>   region of a square is proportional to the
>   area of the region, indeed, is the area of the region divided by the area of the square. Since the coin is 3/8 inch in
>   radius, its center must not land within 3/8 inch of any edge if the player is to
>   win. This restriction generates a square of side 1/4 inch within which the
>   center of the coin must lie for the coin to be in the square. Since the proba-
>   bilities are proportional to areas, the probability of winning is (1/4)^2 = 1/16.
>   Of course, since there is a chance that the coin falls off the table altogether,
>   the total probability of winning is smaller still. Also the squares can
>   be made smaller by merely thickening the lines. If the lines are 1/16 inch
>   wide, the winning central area reduces the probability to (3/16)^2 = 9/256 or
>   less than 1/28.

Now I understand the solution till it says that the probability of winning is 1/16. But what is happening after that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If the penny doesn't land on the table, it's clearly not within a square, so this is a loss.  The $1/16$ probability is conditional on the penny landing on the table.  If you include a non-zero probability of the penny missing the table altogether, the probability of winning goes down.
- The solution assumes ideal (infinitely thin) lines dividing the squares.  The loss criterion is that the penny touches a line.  If the lines are thicker, this reduces the size of the square that the penny must land on, and reduces the winning probability.